# Stack with swiperefreshlayout with collapsingtoolbarlayout

Tags: android, layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, swiperefreshlayout

I want put  `SwipeRefreshLayout` outside the `CoordinatorLayout` containing `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. When I scroll up to the top, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` works ok (collapse the view inside). But I sroll down, it doesn't expand the view, it shows icon refresh for refresh.
How could I scroll down, it expands the view and after that show icon refresh.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/srl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/white"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/layout_merchant_headerinfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_translucent"
                    app:elevation="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <include layout="@layout/fragment_merchant_detail_content" />


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle listener for `AppBarLayout`

```
public abstract class AppBarStateChangeListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    public enum State {
        EXPANDED,
        COLLAPSED,
        IDLE
    }

    private State mCurrentState = State.IDLE;

    @Override
    public final void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.EXPANDED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.EXPANDED);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.EXPANDED;
        } else if (Math.abs(i) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.COLLAPSED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.COLLAPSED);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.COLLAPSED;
        } else {
            if (mCurrentState != State.IDLE) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.IDLE);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.IDLE;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state);
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot!